# How to divide uneven numbers of images for columns

Tags: php, math

I have a layout with four column and I want to add images even to each column as possible. No problem if I have 60 images, then I would have 15 images in each column, but what if I have 43 or 55 or any other uneven number of images!? If I divide 55 to 4 i get 13.75. How can I calculate to get a result like 14 + 14 + 14 + 13 ?

column 1 = 14

column 2 = 14

column 3 = 14

column 4 = 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round up, calculate the number of images per column:

```
$number_of_columns = 4;
$images_per_column = ceil(count($images) / $number_of_columns);
```

Then, use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the `$images` array into chunks of that size (the last one will come out smaller):

```
$image_columns = array_chunk($images, $images_per_column);
```

You will then have a multidimensional array - an array with 4 arrays of images inside it.

You can loop over it like so:

```
<?php foreach ($image_columns as $images_in_column): ?>
<div class="column">
  <?php foreach ($images_in_column as $column_image): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $column_image; ?>" />
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Instead of the foreach loop, would it be possible to just get for different variables?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do that, but yes, you can use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) on the final `$image_columns` array as follows: `$image_columns = list($column_1, $column_2, $column_3, $column_4);`. Then you'll have 4 arrays of images called `$column_1`, `$column_2` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I need variables because I use a SQL question for each column and just want items with ID between 1 and 14 for the first column and for the second column items with ID between 15 to 29 and so on.... Perhaps not the best solution, but it works. When new items is added to the table, this calculation will set the new number of items for each columns automatically. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the minimum number of images per column. Then calculate the remainder. Then spread the remainder to the first N columns.

Here is how to do it in Javascript. The function split() is generalized for any number of columns.

```
function split(n_images, num_of_columns) {

    var min = Math.floor(n_images / num_of_columns);
    var remainder = n_images % num_of_columns;
    var columns = Array.apply(null, Array(num_of_columns)).map(function(value, index) {
        return (index < remainder? min + 1: min);
    });
    return columns;
}

var n_images = 55;
var num_of_columns = 4;
var columns = split(n_images, num_of_columns);
```